How to extract a member from union type?
Consider the following minimal reproduceable ("MRE") example:
// library.d.ts
import type { Bar } from './bar.d.ts';
export interface Foo {
  bar?: string | Bar | boolean;
  // and many other properties
}

// bar.d.ts
export interface Bar {
  baz?: number
  // and many other properties
}

I would like to extract out the Bar type from the union Foo['bar'], so I can use it in a module. How can I do that, without separately importing Bar from the library?
Let's assume bar.d.ts is not available to import for external consumers of the library.
This did not work: Extract<Foo['bar'], Bar> (it requires me to import Bar, which defeats the purpose).

What's the problem with importing Bar?

I would rather not have to write unnecessary imports, if I can just grab it from a type I already have. Just good practice.

In TypeScript, when you want to extract a specific member from a union type, you typically use conditional types to filter out the type you're interested in. However, in the scenario you've described, the direct extraction using something like Extract<Foo, Bar> won't work without having Bar explicitly available for reference in your code.

type Bar = Foo & {}

Well, I see it the other way around. Good practice is also about writing clean an understandable code. I find it cleaner to import the actual type you are using, instead of mangling around with some other type.

@Magnus It's not an unnecesary import, you intend to use it in your own code, even if it's just for passing it around. Besides, if you use Foo and in turn Foo uses Bar, Bar becomes your dependency too.

@MattTimmermans How will Foo & {} remove anything of string or boolean from Foo?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJysg3gWAFDLIwD2xAXMgM5hSgDmANPoQEYYUgCuAti9ANz4AvvnxgAngAcUAMVLIAvGgzIAPlRr01yFqQA2EOCEF4xUlOgBei5HOLIAZNhF4J05dxsBRAB41EYAA8dgzKUAB8JvgGYMjMyD4UVjY0nBBMBMjiSXDWSgBEcBq0IHT5GYSWOXnYRKQUhdQlZaFsUBQAzEIVcZk+iR4pUGk94tmDBUVN9OXxllUTtSTkyI2apeU6KhQArEL8QA See this fiddle, even after doing type Baz = Foo & {} you can still assign let x: Baz = true; Wheras this is not possible anymor if you do type Bam = Extract<Foo, Bar>;

"I would rather not have to write unnecessary imports, if I can just grab it from a type I already have. Just good practice.". This isnt actually the right mindset at all. The structure of types matters and deriving one type from another creates inherent complexity/ logical dependencies which generally makes code harder to change in future and less portable. The actual best practice and right thing to do here absolutely is to import it. To focus on removing an  import rather than the logical dependencies between types (and reducing them), is actually significantly worse and misses the point.

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] where we can see the definition of Bar. For all we know it's a type alias of number in which case the suggestion of Foo & object (not {}, folks, it should be object) won't work. Without a [mre] there aren't enough details.

^^ Or if it's a union of another primitive type (like number) and an object type, in which case & object gives you only part of Bar. If Bar  is available as an export, the clean, simple, maintainable thing is to import it. It makes no sense to derive it. (Now, if it weren't available as an export, that would change things...)

While you could do type Bar = Exclude<Foo, string | boolean>;, if Bar is available to import that's fragile (breaks if more members are added to Foo), unnecessarily-complex, and surprising to other people trying to maintain the code.

Sorry.  Worked for me in vscode

@T.J.Crowder I thought about that, but decided not to go down that route due to the issue you mentioned, and the fact that there are a lot of members on Foo.

@jcalz I updated the OP with an MRE.

@Magnus - Your question starts out with Foo as a union (and above you've said it has a lot of members), but the code you've just added has it as an interface instead with a property whose type is Bar | boolean | undefined. Is Foo a union, or a simple object type? Did you mean bar (lower-case b) has a union type with lots of other members in it other than Bar? Not trying to bust your ___ :-) , just trying to get an accurate picture so we can answer reasonably.

@T.J.Crowder Updated the OP. In the MRE, Foo['bar'] is the union we want to extract Bar from.

@Magnus - Does that union have any other object types in it? Or just primitives? (Also, the question still starts out saying Foo is a union.)

@T.J.Crowder The type currently only has two primitives and one object type, but it would be wise to assume it can change in the future. Updated the entire OP to be consistent with the MRE.

A couple of approaches for you:
& object
If Bar is the only object type in Foo["bar"], then as indicated in the comments you can exclude all the primitives from Foo["bar"] by using & object:
type ExtractedBar = Foo["bar"] & object;
//   ^? type ExtractedBar = Bar & object

(The & object shown in the type display there can be ignored, it doesn't change how ExtractedBar works.)
Playground
Extract w/subset of Bar
If you can't assume that the type doesn't have other object types in it, then you may be able to use Extract if you an identify a small subset of Bar's features that are stable. You don't need the entirety of Bar, just enough of it.
type ExtractedBar2 = Extract<Foo["bar"], {baz?: number;}>;
//   ^? type ExtractedBar2 = Bar

That works even if Bar has other properties, because Extract extracts the union members that are assignable to the constraint; it's okay if they have extra properties.
Playground - I've added a couple of extra properties to Bar to show that the extracter only needs the one, and I've added another object type to Foo["bar"] to show that we extract just Bar.

Ah, that second approach there was smart, I didn't think of that. I guess the only time it breaks is if Foo['bar'] has other union members that are objects and contain the baz?: number property. Thank you

@Magnus - Yup, you'll need to make sure the second type argument to Extract has enough in it to uniquely identify Bar.
